# Logic error in HTML DOM Node Tree structure simulation in C#

Tags: c#, dom, logic, nullreferenceexception

I am trying to simulate the behavior of the HTML DOM Node Tree in C# using Lists and I'm having trouble while trying to get the siblings of a node.
The Document class (which is just the top of the tree) inherits from the Node class.

> The method to get the next sibling

```
if((Parent.HasChildNodes() && Parent.Children.Length > 1) &&
        Parent._children.IndexOf(this) < Parent.Children.Length - 1)
{
    return Parent.Children[Parent._children.IndexOf(this) + 1];
}
else
{
    return null;
}
```

> The method to append a new child

```
public Node AppendChild(Node node)
{
    _children.Add(node);
    SetChild(node);

    node.Parent = this;
    node.IsConnected = true;

    return node;
}
```

**Obs. 1:** The *_children* field is a `private List<Node>`
**Obs. 2:** The *Children* property is a `public Node[]`, getter: `return _children.ToArray();`
**Obs. 3:** The *HasChildNodes* method: `public bool HasChildNodes() { return Children.Length; }`

**The problem**:
I made a simple experiment by creating 1 Document object and 2 Node objects and appending the nodes to the document, and when I requested the first node's next sibling, it returned null, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Update: The program is working now.